# Html.fromHtml doesn't work in RecyclerView

Tags: android, html, android-recyclerview

Below code doesn't work in recyclerview. The 'mate' word is still in normat font.
Am I doing something wrong? Even using SpannableString fails :/

```
     mTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("How are you, <b>mate</b> ?"));
```

Comment: the line is fine. Are you calling  `setText` somewhere else ?

Comment: can you post where you populate your recycler view

Comment: not calling setText anywhere else
I guarantee you guys that I am populating and setting the adapter properly. Wait, I will create a new file with just a text view and try setting the same string in recyclerview and report again

Comment: ^I did it the above thing... removing the textAllCapsAttribute made it work.
Weird.